# Telerik Kendo Grid Validation with Change Event using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Telerik Kendo Grid with column (medical diagnoses) list. The list is filled with method in the controller. I need to check if  a new added Diagnose is in the list of grid or not (and allow to add only Diagnose that is in the list). The grid uses template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(model => model)
        .Name("ICD10Code")
        .Placeholder(RunStrings.TypeICD10CM)
        .MinLength(3)
        .Delay(300)
        .DataTextField("DisplayText")
        .DataSource(source =>
            source.Read(read =>
                read.Action("GetDiagnosisList", "Run", new { area = "ECLS" })
                    .Data("onAdditionalData")
                )
                .ServerFiltering(true)
        )
        .Events(e => { e.Change("onChange"); })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = RunStrings.TypeICD10CMDescription })
        )
```

I would like to write JavaScript code for `onChange` event, that check if new diagnose is in the list. I need an AJAX call to do this validation.

Comment: OK, so what problem are you having with writing an AJAX call?

Comment: I need help for this (I have not experience in using Ajax). Please add an example for this.

Comment: I have an method GetDiagnosesList in MVC Controller that returns list of Diagnoses. I probably need to use this method in Ajax call to return a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must create a function onChange in script and from where use an ajax call like below..

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("write here the actin result name","controller name")',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: the data which you want to pass using JSON.stringify
        })
```